# Functor with an optional parameter

Tags: c#

we working in the past with Functor and now we want to extend one Functor but optional. Is this possible?
I know that i can extend a function with an optional parameter but can i also do it with a Functor?

This is our actual Functor and now we want one additional parameter for it.

```
public static Functor<DirectoryInfo, String, IList> CreateFunctor
```

Comment: What is a `Functor`?

Comment: I have no idea what a functor is, but assuming it is some type that exists in a library, why do you think it should behave any other from any different function that returns a type, e.g. `MyType DoSomething(...)`? Of course your function needs a valuid signature, which would be `static Functor<...> CreateFunctor(...) { ... }`.

Comment: Sorry for this misspelling.
I mean Func like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-5.0

Comment: Did you try `public static Functor<DirectoryInfo, String, IList> CreateFunctor(WhateverType optionalArg = null) { ... }`?

Comment: correct, but this way doesn't work.
The only way that i found is that i implement two functions for this Func but i think this is a bad solution.

Comment: Interesting question, but I wonder if you have the syntax right for your purpose of creating a Functor. You will need a Functor delegate declaration void Functor<T1,T2,T3>() to let it work and it will only work when T1 is a DirectoryInfo, T2 is a String and T3 is some IList. When you want an extra argument, just add its type to the list of types and you'll need a Functor<T1,T2,T3,T4> but that's easy.. but I'm not sure if you intend that. Regard this as answer when we're defining a type restricted delegate, not "Functors" in a broader, mathematical sense.

Comment: Sorry I did not read your question right. If you want your extra argument to be *optional* I don't know the solution in CSharp actually.. you'll need two delegate types.

Comment: please be more specific about what "doesn´t work" mean. Any exception? Unexpected behaviour? Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I think the current answer, an example of a delegate with optional arguments  refers to an *instance* of the Functor, not the Functor definition itself, which is in terms of *types*. A generic. I have tested below code, which did *not* compile.. so I think it cannot be done with C#

Only if the implementation has the same header it works, so both functions should include the *optional* parameter (that is: have the shape of Func2)

```
namespace ConsoleApp1 
{
 public delegate void Functor2<T1,T2,T3>(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, int epar = 0);

 class Program
 {
    public static Functor2<DirectoryInfo, string, IList> MyFunc1;
    public static Functor2<DirectoryInfo, string, IList> MyFunc2;

    public static void Func1(DirectoryInfo d, string s, IList somelist)
    { }

    public static void Func2(DirectoryInfo d, string s, IList somelist, int epar = 0)
    { }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyFunc1 = Func1; // I get a red line here !
        MyFunc1 = Func2;
    }
  }
}
```